# Multiselect listbox with checkbox in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF project and I would like to have a **listbox** with **checkbox** on each **ListboxItem** and have an ObservableCollection to store checked ListboxItems.

I need to move **checked chars** from one ObservableCollection to another ObservableCollection.

With this code I can select multiple checkboxes but when I trigger the command **MoveChar** (command to move chars to another ObservableCollection) via the button **only one ListboxItem moves** and I need to **click it more times** to move all the checked chars.

**View**

```xml
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding Chars}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedCharsIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChars, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Char}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public CharModel SelectedChars { 
    get { return _selectedChars; }
    set { _selectedChars = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

```cs
MoveChar = new RelayCommand(
    () =>
    {
        if (SelectedChars != null)
        {
            TestChars.Add(SelectedChars);
            Chars.Remove(SelectedChars);
            Selected = false;
        }

    });
```

When I change `SelectedChars` to `ObservableCollection<CharModel>` it doesn´t work at all. In ViewModel I iterate each item via `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding `SelectedChars` to the `SelectedItem` property which is for use with Single selection listboxes and will only return a single object, not a collection.  Try binding to the [SelectedItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property.  Be sure the "Items" part is plural.  You will need to refactor the property type to be a SelectedObjectCollection as well but this inherits IList so you can iterate the same.